# Setting gradle system property in .gradle file

Tags: gradle

I have a "general.gradle" file that sets the common properties for all of my projects.
This file is committed to git repository and shared among many users.
I would like to add a system property to is so it will be common to all the users

such options like systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts

is there a way?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don;t want to use the gradle.properties file for that and have one commited in the project?

Comment: the way we use it is a little different - we have a common project that has the common gradle properties. the gradle.properties file that is kept in the home folder of each user isn't common.
the reason i want to set the properties in some general.gradle file is that it will propagate to all the projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make another file, like `general.properties`, add your system properties there prefixed by `systemProp` and then in `general.gradle` load the properties from that file, like so:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File('{YOUR_PATH}/general.properties'))
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(fileInputStream)
fileInputStream.close()

properties.stringPropertyNames().forEach({key -> ext.set(key, properties.getProperty(key))})
```

and then load it to your root `build.gradle` file in projects, like so:

```
apply from: '{YOUR_PATH}/general.gradle'
```

You can retrieve it from the `ext` property. Following this example, if you put `general.properties` in your project and add there,for example: `spring=dev`. Then you put the property loading code in `general.gradle` and apply it in your `build.gradle`, if you add a task like this in your `build.gradle`:

```
task  testProp << {
String profile = getProperty('spring')
System.setProperty('Spring.profiles.active', profile)
String prop = System.getProperty('Spring.profiles.active');
println prop
}
```

then the task execution should print out `dev`.

Comment: could you please explain - how should I run the first part?
and what does the 
properties.stringPropertyNames().forEach({key -> ext.set(key, properties.getProperty(key))}) does?

Comment: Ok. So you don't really need to run it; you just put a general.properties file in the project; then you put this code in general.gradle and once you apply general.gradle to your build.gradle file, you don't need to execute anything manually; gradle will execute it for you and using the forEach statement, key-value pairs in the `ext` value and then you can use it in your gradle tasks. Actually, I think I should still modify this answer with the way it can be used. Let me do that.

Comment: Np :) let me know if it works; I've tried it and seems to work fine.

Comment: Sorry, ended up modifying it. Just setting `systemProp.` prefixed value will not be enough. You need to actually set the system value from that loaded one explicitly in one of the tasks in your project setup. I think you can use it similarly just if you add this to tasks, but if it's not sufficient for you, feel free to revoke the answer approval.

Comment: actually System.setProperty('some.prop', val) works fine so this is great for me